# Can turning off drm_kms_helper polling affect screen brightness control?

Tags: xorg, kms

I have a Samsung R430 notebook that has been running Ubuntu for close to a year, now. Since I've upgrated to Maverick, I've been dealing with little, but increasingly annoying issues, that put my faith to question.

The first one, a CPU-intensive set of drm_kms_helper, made me compile my own kernel and set polling to off just so I could move my mouse without frequent stuttering. That led me to dealing with a screen that gets dimmer and dimmer after each sleep/wake-up cycle, which eventually leads me to reboot.

Since I have seen some KMS and brightness related bugs around, I was wondering if it is a definite cause for my problem. If so, has there been any advance on the excessive polling issue for those of us plagued by it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of compiling your own kernel, you can disable polling at boot time. Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add this line:

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

You'll likely need to open a bug report for the other issue, though.